# How did the Portuguese pronoun "se" take on these other functions?

Tags: historical-linguistics, pronouns, portuguese

In Portuguese, the third person accusative pronoun *se* ("himself/herself/itself/themselves") can be used for four different purposes:

1.) Most straightforwardly, as a reflexive pronoun:

```
Mantém-se     forte
Keeps-himself strong
"He keeps himself strong"
```

2.) As a reciprocal marker:

```
Amam-se
Love-themselves
"They love each other"
```

3.) As a particle for subject indetermination:

```
Vive-se       bem  neste   país
Lives-oneself well in this country
"One lives well in this country"
```

4.) As a passivizing particle:

```
Vende-se     esta casa
Sells-itself this house
"This house is being sold"
```

How did this pronoun develop to fulfil such different functions? Also, is this unique to Portuguese or has it occurred in other languages as well?

Comment: If anyone thinks the interlinear gloss can be improved (which must be the case), feel free to edit it.

Comment: In addition, in the plural *se* can be a reciprocal marker too e.g *Eles amam-se* "they love each other".

Comment: Very well observed, @Mark! I had forgotten that.

Comment: I know that Spanish and French use "pseudopassive" _se_. It's an interesting type of grammaticalizationa, reflexive > middle

Comment: I believe Italian *si* can be used similarly.

Comment: Polish *się* '...self' has the same meanings.

Comment: It's interesting to me that this kind of construction exists in (at least some of) the Slavic languages too, which probably indicates that its origins are older than Latin.

Comment: @DavidWallace yes, as hinted at in my answer below regarding the Proto-indoeuropean mediopassive and the PIE reflexive particle _*se-_

Comment: Ah, sorry @MarkBeadles.  I haven't been hanging round here for long enough.  I see "PIE is reconstructed" and I think about food, not about proto-Indoeuropean.  Yours is a really good answer, BTW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand it this is an evolution from the PIE reflexive to a new mediopassive.

PIE is often reconstructed as having [two voices](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/286368/Indo-European-languages/74556/Morphology-and-syntax?anchor=ref603307), active and mediopassive. Classical Latin had separate [verb forms in **-r**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Latin/Lesson_2-Active_v_Passive) that marked the mediopassive. ([This -r form was also found throughout Italoceltic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italo-Celtic#Forms), Tocharian, and Hittite.)

Separately, PIE ***se-** -> Classical Latin **sē** (**sēsē**, **sibi**, **suī**) was almost purely a reflexive marker, with some use as a reciprocal marker (e.g. **inter sē**).

As the Romance languages developed, the **-r** mediopassive became disused even for [deponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deponent_verb#Latin) verbs. I'm not confident why this happened; perhaps it was due to forms becoming homophonous. Anyway, with the loss of the old mediopassive a new form was adopted for the voice.  The reflexive **sē** filled this role. In the daughter languages **sē** -> *Fr, Es, Pt, Ro* **se**, *It* **si**.

So in Portuguese, and many of the other Romance languages, the reflexive/reciprocal and mediopassive are formed using **se**. The "subject indetermination" and "passiving" functions you describe use **se** as part of this new "mediopassive"; i.e., indeterminate or impersonal subjects regarded as a middle voice.

**EDIT**: Miller (2010) has a treatment of this question in "[The Mediopassive: Latin to Romance](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof%3aoso/9780199583430.001.0001/acprof-9780199583430-chapter-8)":

> Reflexive sē
>   forms replaced the ‐r forms in different structures at different
>   times. The replacement began in the ergative verbs where ‘I sank
>   myself’ had a bound anaphor in contrast to the lack of agentivity in
>   the type ‘the ship sank itself’ , reanalyzed as an anticausative with
>   reflexive merged in a projection for derived imperfectivity.
>   Subsequently, the sē construction replaced the ‐r forms in certain
>   other structures, and finally the middle and impersonal, but not the
>   passive (within Latin, at least).

Comment: Fascinating! I didn't know about middle and mediopassive voices.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Two questions: 1. The Latin passive was rarely used to mark reflexivity; so isn't it better to call it "passive" rather than "mediopassive"? 2. Portuguese uses the past participle + a form of *ser* + *por* for passive sentences where there is an agent. The word "mediopassive" is normally used only where there is no passive voice, to encompass both middle and passive; but that is not really the case here, so wouldn't it be better to call what *se* does the "middle voice"? (Or possibly not a voice at all, as it is rather a particle with different functions.)

Comment: Another question: as you say, *se* filled the hole left by the Latin passive in indeterminate subjects (Otavio's 3) and agentless passives (4). But the passive-with-agent came to be expressed by *ser* + past participle; so do you have any idea why 3 and 4 did not come to be expressed by *ser* + past participle, i.e. why the Latin passive was split into *se* and *ser* + p.p. respectively along these lines in Portuguese (and I think Spanish and Italian too)?

Comment: @Cerberus, in Portuguese, the agentless passive voice can also be expressed by ser/estar + past participle. So, the example (4) could be rephrased as "Esta casa está sendo vendida". Or, as in *Encontrou-se a solução* / *A solução foi encontrada*, "The solution has been found".

Comment: @Cerberus Although the Latin mediopassive was not used generally for reflexivity, it was used in middle senses (anticausatives and other unaccusatives), e.g. *vulnus clauditur* `wound-nom close-3sg-R` "the wound heals".

Comment: @MarkBeadles: Hmm, it depends on your definition of "middle voice": I would have it include reflexivity, like the Greek middle voice; but you could centre it on the intransitive use of a verb that is otherwise used transitively, as you say. Two remarks: 1. I believe the Latin passive cannot be used like that with all verbs: it depends on the verb and the writer. During the Empire and later, I believe it was less common than in archaic Latin. 2. Active verbs could be used in precisely the same way, just as in English: *auxit cura* "his worry increased" v. *auxit curam* "he increased his worry".

Comment: @Cerberus this discussion about what a middle voice is would make a good question (hint, hint) :)

Comment: [Done.](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/what-is-a-middle-voice)