# What is a middle voice and a medio-passive voice?

Tags: terminology, grammatical-voice

In order to [explain the evolution of the third person accusative pronoun in IE languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1684/22), Mark Beadles makes use of the concepts of middle and medio-passive voices. But the discussion that followed his answer seems to show that these concepts are not so clear to everyone. So, what exactly is a middle voice (and a medio-passive voice, for that matter)?

Comment: Hi Otavio, I took the liberty to change the title, I hope you don't mind. I think including a more specific term like this will help our readers who are just title-spotting and also increase our search engine visibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find a decent overview of valency-changing processes, with some comments on the term *middle* in [Dixon & Aikhenvald (2000: secs.3--5, esp. pp.11--12)](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam032/99024413.pdf), and references therein. Those authors suggest that the term is used with a wide variety of senses, and recommend that it be avoided (almost) altogether because of its ambiguity. Rather than insert a long block quote, I'd encourage interested people to just click through to the PDF and read the passage on pp.11--12.

Two works that Dixon and Aikhenvald cite that may be worth consulting are [Kemmer (1993)](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_middle_voice.html?id=mQv0QmkTHbMC) and [Keyser & Roeper (1984)](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4178392?uid=3739832&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=55942714153)

Answer (score 9):

In my favorite dictionary of linguistic terms, "A Dictionary of Grammatical Terms in Linguistics" by R. L. Trask from 1993, **middle** is given four meanings, the fourth of which is a synonym of **mediopassive**.

A **mediopassive** is a transitive verb with a passive meaning but intransitve form, syntactically. Examples from the book are 1) *This fabric washes easily* and 2) *My new book is selling well*.There aren't that many such in English but in other languages it is productive, like in Basque. Verbs that can be used both transitively and intransitively are also called **labile verbs**.